# Macro to delete the first rows in all existing sheets in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with around 300 sheets for which I need to remove the first rows.
Could you please suggest VBA code for doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try use `for each sheets` loop :) . Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Atleast try to post what you have tried.

below code will delete 1st in all sheets in active workbook

```
Sub LoopThroughSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

     ws.Range("1:1").Delete

    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the both proposals. The first one did not run, but the second one ( provided by Sathish K) did the job. Thank you guys!

Comment: Glad i could help . don't forget to accept the appropriate answer

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub deleteRows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Range("A1").EntireRow.Delete
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please update the macro with task do replace all "*" with "" (* with empty symbol) for the first row after the deletion. I mean after the first row is deleted the replacement to be done for the new first row in every sheet. If it is done with two cycles is fine too.